# BodyParser not parsing request using POSTMAN

Tags: node.js, api, body-parser

For some reason that I can't find out why, my bodyParser isn't parsing my requests from my api (title and content). They appear to be `undefined`

**app.js**

```
const EXPRESS = require('express');
const FEED_ROUTES = require('./routes/feed');
const BODY_PARSER = require('body-parser');
const APP = EXPRESS();

APP.use(BODY_PARSER.json());
APP.use(BODY_PARSER.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
APP.use('/feed', FEED_ROUTES);

APP.listen(8080);
```

controller js

```
exports.getPosts = (req, res, next) => {
  res
    .status(200)
    .json({ posts: [{ title: 'test', content: 'This is a post ' }] });
};

exports.createPost = (req, res, next) => {
  const title = req.body.title;
  const content = req.body.content;
  console.log(title);
  res.status(201).json({
    message: 'Post created succesfully!',
    post: { id: new Date().toISOString(), title: title, content: content }
  });
};
```

POSTMAN prints this:

```
{
    "message": "Post created succesfully!",
    "post": {
        "id": "2019-07-09T00:24:57.129Z"
    }
}
```

**WORKS**
[image]

**DOESNT WORK**
[image]

Comment: What does the HTTP request look like? How did you send the request?

Comment: ```{
 "body" : {
  "title": "My first Post!",
  "content": "My first creation of post works"
 }
}```

I have tried to do it without the body property { "title" : "....",...}

@shaochuancs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send the request with

1. HTTP Header `Content-Type: application/json`
2. Valid JSON body

To achieve above using Postman v7.2.2, please see screenshot below

[image: Send JSON request using Postman]

Comment: omg!! lol I was missing the JSON(application/json) options! you are a genius!